# Looking for recommendations on a router than can survive in a factory-like environment

Tags: router

We own a carwash. Our router is in the room where all of the soap, wax, chemicals etc are stored and dispensed. The room is pretty grimy all the time, humid, dust and moisture always in the air etc. We have replaced the router 3 times in the past 2 years because it keeps failing. Unfortunately, it's a "self serve" carwash meaning that there is no other place to have the router. (This room is literally the central hub of the carwash. All of the soap and chemicals come out of the room, networking is done in the room, credit card processing, etc.)

I'm hesitant to put a router inside of a "weatherproof" case because the room tends to get pretty warm in the summer (Though, I don't have exact temps).

Any recommendations on a router than can survive in this type of environment??